# Play a sound only using phone audio

Tags: android

I'm developing a sort of alarm clock application and I need to play my sound specifically through the phone audio and *not through Bluetooth*. (I learned this the hard way as I missed all three of my set alarms this morning because the alarms played through my Bluetooth headset)

How can I play a sound that only plays through phone audio and not Bluetooth?

Comment: Have you tried audiomanager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar requirement when user select an option, i need to play audio from speaker. so i changed audio stream type to ring like mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING) and it worked. Hope this works for you too. (NOTE: some phones have limitation that audio is played from both speaker and bluetooth)